# Angular get latitude and longitude from place id in google maps component

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to get the latitude and longitude from google maps prediction information. Currently, I am using the [google-maps](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps#readme) component.

I've managed to get a search bar in with `ngx-google-places-autocomplete` as well. What I need is to get the coordinates of the first search result item when the user clicks enter.
Here is what I have so far:

```
<input
    id="over_map"
    ngx-google-places-autocomplete
    class="form-control location-search d-flex justify-content-center"
    #placesRef="ngx-places"
    [(ngModel)]="searchLocation"
    (autocomplete)="valueCompleted($event)"
    (keydown)="onKeydown($event,searchLocation)"
    (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)"/>
    <google-map
      id="google_map"
      height="330px"
      width="100%"
      [center]="center"
      [zoom]="zoom"
      [options]="options"
      (mapClick)="clickLocation($event)"
    >
      
    </google-map>
```

in my `onKeydown` method:

```js
  onKeydown($event: KeyboardEvent, searchLocation) {
    if ($event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.map.getCenter()));
      let searchPrediction: any;

      const displaySuggestions = function(
      predictions: google.maps.places.QueryAutocompletePrediction[],
      status: google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus
    ) {
      if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Current prediction', predictions[0]);
      console.log('Location Details:', predictions[0].place_id);
      searchPrediction = predictions[0];
    };
      const service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
      service.getQueryPredictions({ input: this.searchLocation }, displaySuggestions);

      }
  }
```

This will get all the prediction items and get the first of them all as seen by `predictions[0]`. As far as I can tell, I can only get the `place id` from this.

Example, the search results for `mon`, look as below:

```
description: "Montreal, QC, Canada", id: "64f76606728b9536f3b6f03703a296affd47ca6c", matched_substrings: Array(1), place_id: "ChIJDbdkHFQayUwR7-8fITgxTmU", reference: "ChIJDbdkHFQayUwR7-8fITgxTmU", …}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not calling [Places Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) which will include the necessary data that you need such as `geometry` which will provide the latlng coordinates of the selected place. I suggest that you take a look at the Autocomplete Widget to get an idea on how to do this in vanillaJS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking at this right now, I made a work around in the following way:

```js
 onKeydown($event: KeyboardEvent, searchLocation) {
    if ($event.key === 'Enter') {
      this.readyForSubmit = true;
    }
    if (this.searchLocation) {
      this.zoomToSearch();
    }
  }


  private zoomToSearch() {
    const displaySuggestions = function (
      predictions: google.maps.places.QueryAutocompletePrediction[],
      status: google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus
    ) {
      if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }

      const completeUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=' + predictions[0].place_id + '&key=API-KEY-HERE';
      axios.get(completeUrl)
        .then(response => {
          // get the first item from the results
          searchPrediction = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
    const service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    // get the input value 
    service.getQueryPredictions({ input: this.searchLocation }, displaySuggestions);
    service.getQueryPredictions({ input: this.searchLocation }, displaySuggestions);
    this.location = searchPrediction;
  
  }
```

As you can follow, once results re-obtained, I get the first item. My HTML file:

```
<input 
    id="over_map" ngx-google-places-autocomplete
    class="form-control location-search d-flex justify-content-center" #placesRef="ngx-places"
    [(ngModel)]="searchLocation" (keydown)="onKeydown($event,searchLocation)"
    (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)" />

    <google-map 
        id="google_map" 
        height="330px" 
        width="100%" 
        [center]="center" 
        [zoom]="zoom" 
        [options]="options"
        (mapClick)="clickLocation($event)">
       
         <map-marker 
           (mapDrag)="markerDragLocation($event)" 
           [position]="marker.position" 
           [title]="marker.title"
           [options]="marker.options">
         </map-marker>
    </google-map>
```

In this case, you can listen to a specific key event.In my case, I chose the **enter** key while using `ngModel` to bind the search term.

This seems to work fine, making it possible to click to get the co-ordinaes or search to get the first item from the drop down.